# How to check if Azure Service Fabric is up and running?

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

Is there a way to programmatically check if Service Fabric is up and running from an external client? I thought about just using try catch blocks but I'm curious whether there's a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Do you mean to check if your Service Fabric cluster is running, or if a specific Application or Service within an Application is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single "is the cluster running?" command. There are different ways that question can be interpreted.

But for an external client, the simplest check you can do is to simply try to communicate with the cluster. The cluster may be "running" but if your client can't communicate with it then it can stop right there. To do that programmatically you do have to catch a communication exception. Here is an example:

```
FabricClient client = new FabricClient();

try
{
    await client.QueryManager.GetProvisionedFabricCodeVersionListAsync();
}
catch (FabricTransientException ex)
{
    if (ex.ErrorCode == FabricErrorCode.CommunicationError)
    {
         // can't communicate with the cluster!
    }
}
```

You're basically waiting for the connection to time out, so it will take a few seconds for this check to complete.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is: "How can I check if My Service in Azure Service Fabric is up and running?" then you have some options. *(If your question on the other hand is: "How can I check if Azure Service Fabric cluster 
is up and running?" then you should look at [Vaclav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41813714/1062217).)*

Create a new instance of [`FabricClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient), now you can do a lot of fun stuff, including checking the health of your services.

If your cluster is secured (which is recommended) then you need to supply the `X509Credentials`. You can follow this article for that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-to-secure-cluster.

```cs
    var connection = "myclustername.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19000";
    var fabricClient = new FabricClient(GetCredentials(clientCertThumb, serverCertThumb, CommonName), connection);
```

Using the associated manager clients you can check the health state of services deployed to your cluster.

Using the [`FabricClient.ServiceHealthManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.healthclient) to check individual partitions:

```cs
var serviceHealth = await fabricClient.HealthManager.GetServiceHealthAsync(serviceName);
foreach (var serviceHealthPartitionHealthState in serviceHealth.PartitionHealthStates)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Health state: {serviceHealthPartitionHealthState.PartitionId} {serviceHealthPartitionHealthState.AggregatedHealthState}");
}
```

Using [`FabricClient.QueryManagerClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.queryclient) to check aggregated health of each service:

```cs
var serviceList = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetServiceListAsync(applicationName);
foreach (var service in serviceList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\tFound service {service.ServiceName} {service.ServiceStatus} {service.HealthState}");
}
```

If any of these evaluate to anything else than `System.Fabric.Health.HealthState.Ok` then your service might have some problems.